# Image is not setting to fill_parent in Imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Image is not displaying in full width even I give  (android:layout_width="fill_parent") to my Imageview class

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/middle1"
      />
```

Here I got my Bitmap

```
 if (orientation != 0) {
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(orientation);
                        bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                                bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    } else
                        bMapRotate = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, bmp.getWidth(),
                                bmp.getHeight(), true);
                    findViewById(R.id.img).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//Here I set the bitmap                 ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img)).setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
                    findViewById(R.id.preview).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I cant understand why it is not taking full length of screen eventhough I give fill_parent to imageview in my xml

Comment: try to play with scale properity

Comment: are u doing setImageBitmap?? and u r using matrix for Bitmap??

Comment: What are you doing? do you want to Scale image same as device screen size on change of orientation?

Comment: what is your parent layout of your ImageView? can you post more snippest from your xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) element of ImageView. You probably want fitXY I think...

Answer (score 0):

```
  setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
```

Try this to your ImageView and make sure your bitmap after creating is returning the same width to ScreenWidth